# Will only plot Factors?

Tags: r, string, plot, factors

Im working in my new Data set and I always start it with

```
 options(StringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The problem im having now, is that R will only plot the Data I set if the strings as factors options is set to TRUE.

Whenever I try to plot with Stringsasfactors = FALSE it will give me the next Error message.

```
plot(Data$Jobs, Data$RXH)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

But when I set Stringsasfactors TRUE it plots it without problem...

This is the script.

```
#Setting WD.

getwd()
setwd("C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/Documents/R proj")


options(stringsAsFactors = F)
get <- read.csv("WorkExcelR.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
Data <- na.omit(get)
```

And this is Data$Jobs and Data$RXH

```
> Data$Jobs
[1] "Playstation"  "RWC Heineken" "Jagermeister" "RWC Heineken"
[5] "RWC Heineken" "RWC Heineken"
> Data$RXH
[1]  90  90 100  90  90  90
```

Comment: `plot(factor(Data$Jobs), Data$RXH)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are illustrating stems from the fact that there is a `plot.factor` function but no `plot.character` function. You can see the available plot.-methods by typing:

```
methods(plot)
```

This is not particularly well described in the help page for `?plot`, but there is a separate help page for `?plot.factor`. Functions in R are dispatched on the basis of their arguments: S3 functions on the basis only of the class of their first argument and S4 methods on the basis of their argument signatures. In a sense the `plot.factor` function elaborates on that strategy, because it then dispatches to different plotting routines based on the second argument's class as well, assuming it is matched by position or named `y`.

You have a couple of choices: Force the plot method which then needs to be caled using the `:::` infix function since plot.factor is not exported or do the coercion yourself or call a more specific plotting type.

```
graphics:::plot.factor(Data$Jobs, Dat
plot(factor(Data$Jobs), Data$RXH)
boxplot(Data$RXH ~Data$Jobs)    # which is the result if x is factor and y is numeric
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! That helped me! !!